# is it possible to preform search across all mongoldb collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to preform a search across all documents of a MongoDB collection?

I want a way to search for keywords on my collections. I am using mongoose and prefer not to adjust the "Schema" as the whole logic on backend is depending on the "Schema" i have written earlier.

Kindly, note that there are subdocuments and references to other collections .

Comment: You can retrieve from mongo the list of all collections and then perform the search individually.